# TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS error code in Android C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

In Android C2DM documentation there's an error called "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS" which they describe it as the following :

> *The user has too many applications registered. The application should tell the user to uninstall some other applications, let user retry manually. Fix on the device side.*

What it really means?, does it mean that there's a lot of Apps that use's C2DM are running on the same phone. if so is there any known estimate of the number of Apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each C2DM user can have at most 100 installed apps that use C2DM. This limit appears to just be an arbitrary safeguard that Google enacted to prevent abuse.

See here for more: http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/3f5ee56670a8254d

Answer (score 1):

According to GCM document you get error TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS when your device have 100 different application that is register with google server. So you app should be prepared to handle the registration error TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS. This error indicates that the device has too many apps registered with GCM.

Comment: Can you please also share what's the best way to handle the registration error TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS? And how to fix this.